# Videojs autoplay and no controls on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, html5-video, video.js

Is there a possible configuration for video.js that hides native controls on iPhone? I'd like to also be able to autoplay, but that's significantly less important. My main concern is to be able to use my nicely designed javascript controls, instead of the ugly, clunky native controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `video` element is very constrained on iPhone. If you want to play HTML5 video at all, you have to use the native fullscreen player. iPads offer more freedom but are still limited compared to desktop browsers. Neither device allows autoplay. [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1) has more details.